# SQL Syntax Problems

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im trying to do this:

```
String insertQuery=" DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE Username= " + Username + ";";
```

But im getting this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'sam' in 'where clause'
```

Its getting the right username etc I know this by testing, I assume the syntax is wrong but im getting no syntax errors?

The table is called Accounts. The coloums are Username & Password,

Comment: I think you need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) before you cause a disaster. Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: [Exploits Of A Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing single quotes. In your case(it's string) variable need to be wrapped in them or it'll be interpreted as column.

```
String insertQuery = "DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE Username = '" + Username + "'";
```

### Recommendation:

Hence i recommend you to use **placeholders** to avoid this kind of problem. Don't forget to care about a security([SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) for instance). It's worth to say that *parametrized statements* are also more human-readable, safer and faster as well.

I don't like "hardcoded" queries. Let's imagine a scenario if you had a table with ten columns and imagine how you query will look in this case: **absolutely human-unreadable**.

An usage of parametrized statements is always very efficient and comfortable practise. Your code looks good and becomes human-readable and what is "main" solution is much more safer and cleaner.

Have look at [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Basic example:

```
private final String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE Username = ?";

public boolean deleteObject(String username) {
   Connection c = null;
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   try {
      c = DataSource.getConnection();
      ps = c.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
      ps.setString(1, username); // numbering starts with 1 not 0!
      return ps.executeUpdate() > 0;
   }
   catch (SQLException ex) {
      System.out.println("Error in deleteObject() method: " + ex.getMessage());
      return false;
   }
   finally {
      if (c != null) {
         try {
            c.close();
         }
         catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in closing conn: " + ex.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The single quotes need to be inside the string literal

Comment: No need to apologize! Just upvote my answer j/k!  +1 for the edit.

Comment: @KevinBowersox when you added comment i just update answer myself.. stay calm.

Comment: I was joking about the upvote, but thanks! BTW, perfectly calm!

Comment: Agreed about the approach, I was just answering the question.  This could be for a POC or something simple.

Comment: @KevinBowersox so answer took a little attention so i just updated it.

Answer (score 2):

If username is a varchar you need to add single quotes around the value in the where clause.

```
String insertQuery=" DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE Username= '" + Username + "';";
```

Since the value is not quoted its identifying the username, I'm assuming its Sam as a column.

Comment: String concatenation is not a valid way of constructing a query unless that value is properly escaped.